# making WiFi adapter run in dual mode - STA and AP

Tags: wifi, linux, wireless-adapter, hotspot

I am trying to make RaLink RT 5370 WiFi adapter run in dual mode - station as well as AP. I have tiny core linux installed on PI, built on top of 3.18.10 linux kernel version. I have been able to make dual mode work effectively on Atheros based adapter, but the same steps do not work for RT5370.
Once PI connects to WiFi through wlan0 interface, I fire the below sequence of commands -

```
#1. To create wlan1 in Master mode
iw dev wlan0 interface add wlan1 type __ap

#2. To assign IP to wlan1 interface
ifconfig wlan1 up 192.168.7.1
```

The above command fails with the error -

> *ifconfig: SIOCSIFFLAGS: Device or resource busy*

and I cannot proceed further. The later steps include bringing up dnsmasq and hostapd.

So, is this driver limitation? And is there a workaround?

Comment: See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40458/can-the-pi-official-wifi-adapter-do-simultaneous-client-ap-modes?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your H/W is not providing you a dual-mode. Actually, as my personal experience shows, ONLY 2 or 3 antennas on adapter can give you a POSSIBILITY of running in dual-mode. I saw an USB-dongle, that ACTUALLY supported it, but due to single antenna construction it's perfomance was awful in dual-mode, but very good as just AP or ST.

Comment: But the Atheros wifi adapter for which dual mode worked, has a single antenna. Also, when first command is fired, iwconfig does show 2 interfaces wlan0 on STA mdoe and wlan1 on Master mode. The problem arises when I fire second command. Also, if I set wlan1 on Monitor mode instead of Master mode, even the second command works, but later hostapd fails with the same error message.

Comment: The number of antennas should not matter.  It won't be transmitting to multiple destinations at the same time anyway as usually, if it can be both a STA and AP at the same time, the AP portion will be locked to the same frequency the STA side uses.

Comment: @MichaelGraff it should not - I agree, but IT DOES. If I wouldn't checked it myself I was never write such a thing. It took me a while to figure it out, and it worked

Comment: Dual antennas does not imply dual radios.  This feels antidotal not scientific.

Comment: @MichaelGraff Antenna sharing between two radios is a BAD idea, as an example you can see a common problem with WiFi+Bluetooth on a single antenna in cheap tablet or phone. Also - I think that a *scientific* explaination of this fact is that 2+ antenna utilizes a MIMO functionality, so one antenna in dual mode works as AP on one channel, and another antenna(s) works as ST on *another* channel, and they are not connected by a contact group, so no interference is occured

Comment: I never said two radios should share a single antenna. I said two antennas does not imply two radios.

Comment: Also, you are wrong about what dual antennas gains you for a single radio.  It does primary two things:  MIMO-style (which uses two antenna 90º out of phase) and diversity, where one antenna receives better than the other for some clients.  However, frequently in a diversity arrangement the radio still uses only one antenna to transmit back.  So once again, two antennas does not imply any additional radio capacity or functionality.